# error in xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null ) using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, html, jquery

i have two files , one is html5 that has a script that loads data from an input and send it using ajax to another php file and show the php response in a div in the html5 page. I'm using the eclipse browser, but i'm having a probleme when i verify my page in the chrome console and i found that there is a problem in this line :

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

This is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
(function ($) {
    // used to keep a reference to the ajax request object
    var searchQuery = false;

    var showUser = function (str) {
        if (searchQuery != false) // if there is a pending request, cancel it
            searchQuery.abort();

        var searchTerm = $('#matr').val();
       //  if (str.trim().length < 1)
       if (searchTerm.trim().length < 1 ){
           $("#txtHint").html('');
            return;
        } 

        // clean up the old accordion
        if ($("#accordion").length > 0)
            $("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
        $("#txtHint").html('searching...');

        searchQuery = $.ajax({
            'url':'http://IP/filename/accueil.php?q='+searchTerm,
            'success':function (response) {
                searchQuery = false;
                $('#txtHint').html(response);
                $('#accordion').accordion();
            },
            'error': function () {
                searchQuery = false;
                $('#txtHint').html('Sorry, there was an error');
            }
        });
    };

    // add the change event to the text field, once the page loads
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#matr').change(showUser);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>    
</head>
<body>     
 <center> 
 <form name="data" >
   <label>Enter the data :</label>
<input type="text"  id="matr"  >
</form></center>
<br>
<center>   
<div id="txtHint"><b>Clique here to show data</b></div></center>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php file has only connection to the sql database , and the :

```
$q =$_GET['q'];
```

to collect the value and show it in a div .

But when i execute i get the error the jquery.js file : 
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Please if you have any idea